# Error while using google chrome on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: google-chrome

```
[28686:28721:0502/102750.745063:ERROR:appcache_update_url_loader_request.cc(139)] Not implemented reached in virtual void content::AppCacheUpdateJob::UpdateURLLoaderRequest::OnTransferSizeUpdated(int32_t)
```

I get this error all the time when I am using google chrome (started from my terminal). I wonder what this issue is.

Chrome version: 73.0.3683.103. (EDIT: same issue with version 74.0.3729.131)

Comment: Does Google Chrome work well (despite the terminal output)? Your version of the browser is also outdated.

Comment: yes it works well. However, this error clutters the log of my browser, and I was just wondering what this issue was.

Comment: Why installing spywares? - `sudo dpkg --purge $(dpkg -l | grep 'chrome' | awk '{print $2}') && sudo apt install chromium-browser` - Take it easy, just kidding... although...

Comment: @DKBose I updated chrome and I still have the same issue.